# Exchange large mailbox

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007

Im currently trying to speed up the searching of an Exchange mailbox containing over 140,000 emails. The mailbox can be accessed by users using Outlook 2007.

Now we want this mailbox to be active at all time without loss of any emails. How can we speed up the process of searching trough a large mailbox without disabling it as it currently takes over 20 minutes to find a specific item?

Comment: Why would searching the mailbox cause you to lose emails? Why would searching the mailbox cause it to be disabled? Why would the mailbox not be "active" (whatever that means)? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @joeqwerty I guess what he/she means is that they don't want to delete emails. I suppose they need the whole history. Maybe it's some kind of log email account. Or an old account which cannot be disabled and to which some important email goes.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Optimize Outlook Search Options**

   1. Open "Search Options" in Outlook (click the little arrow next to the search pane)
   2. Make sure all PST files are indexed
   3. Disable Instant Search ("Display search results as I type")
   4. If you only want to search the Inbox, change the "When searching..." option in the bottom from *All Folders* to *Only the currently selected Folder*

      ---
2. **Upgrade to Exchange 2010 and enable Archiving**

   - If you are more interested in recent mails than older mails, upgrade to Exchange 2010 and enable archiving of mails older than, say, 6 months.
   - When searching the inbox, results found in mails from within the last 6 months reveal themselves.
   - If the result doesn't match your need, search the archive.

     ---
3. **Ask yourself "Why do I use Outlook 2007 to keep track of 140.000 important messages?"**

   - Unless you have a really good reason, like a really specific need for using Outlook 2007 for this, I wouldn't recommend indexing this amount of email with an Outlook account.

     ---

Comment: +1 on why you have 140000 email in mail server that sound like they need a database designed for this use.